# 10.13 - Disable Auto screen lock after Apple Remote Desktop Session

Tags: macos, apple-remote-desktop

Using ARD (Apple Remote Desktop) to login to my Mac Pro running 10.13.6 then exiting the ARD window the Mac Pro locks the screen which is fine sometimes, but not at other times.  I would like to control the ability of it locking the screen after ending the ARD session. Is there a setting that I don't see or know of?

The settings:

- user account is password enabled
- screen saver is enabled for 15 after inactivity
- energy saver for display 10 minutes.

Observations:

- If you logout of the user account then login then start and end a session the screen remains unlocked.
- When the display goes to sleep or screen saver is enabled then start and end a session process locks the screen when closing the ARD window.
- Seems like the sleeping of the screen itself changes the expected behavior.

Question:
 - How do we control the desired behavior to not lock the screen after ARD session without turning off energy saver for the display?

Comment: Thank you for noting those observations. I have been trying to figure out what causes this issue, and it seems you are correct that if the screen sleeps or screensaver starts, macOS shows the login window upon disconnection of ARD sessions. I've been seeing this with a couple headless servers and didn't realize that the screensaver was enabled on both of them.